# Sharpen filter - no effect

Tags: c#, image-processing, filter, bitmap, convolution

The following routine is to sharpen an 8 bit indexed grayscale only.

**This code seems to have no effect on the input image.** That is, what is going in, the same is coming out.

If I increase the value of `strength` the image seems to be getting darker, but, never filtered.

What could be possibly going wrong?

I am using the following kernel,

```
double[,] _numericalKernel = new double[,] 
                             { { -1, -1, -1, }, 
                               { -1,  9, -1, }, 
                               { -1, -1, -1, }, };
```

The following is my source code for sharpening,

```
    public static Bitmap NonfftSharpen(Bitmap image, double[,] mask, double strength)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)image.Clone();

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            int width = bitmap.Width;
            int height = bitmap.Height;

            if (mask.GetLength(0) != mask.GetLength(1))
            {
                throw new Exception("_numericalKernel dimensions must be same");
            }
            // Create sharpening filter.
            int filterSize = mask.GetLength(0);

            double[,] filter = (double[,])mask.Clone();

            int channels = sizeof(byte);
            double bias = 1.0 - strength;
            double factor = strength / 16.0;
            int halfOfFilerSize = filterSize / 2;

            byte[,] result = new byte[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];

            // Lock image bits for read/write.

            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                                        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                        PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            int memorySize = bitmapData.Stride * height;
            byte[] memory = new byte[memorySize];

            // Copy the RGB values into the local array.
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, memory, 0, memorySize);

            int rgb;
            // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.

            for (int y = halfOfFilerSize; y < height - halfOfFilerSize; y++)
            {
                for (int x = halfOfFilerSize; x < width - halfOfFilerSize; x++)
                {
                    for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterSize; filterY++)
                    {
                        double grayShade = 0.0;

                        for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterSize; filterX++)
                        {
                            int imageX = (x - halfOfFilerSize + filterX + width) % width;
                            int imageY = (y - halfOfFilerSize + filterY + height) % height;

                            rgb = imageY * bitmapData.Stride + channels * imageX;

                            grayShade += memory[rgb + 0] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                        }

                        rgb = y * bitmapData.Stride + channels * x;

                        int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * grayShade + (bias * memory[rgb + 0])), 0), 255);

                        result[x, y] = (byte)b;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
            for (int x = halfOfFilerSize; x < width - halfOfFilerSize; x++)
            {
                for (int y = halfOfFilerSize; y < height - halfOfFilerSize; y++)
                {
                    rgb = y * bitmapData.Stride + channels * x;

                    memory[rgb + 0] = result[x, y];
                }
            }

            // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
            Marshal.Copy(memory, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, memorySize);

            // Release image bits.
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            return bitmap;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("input image can't be null");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Um, now which: does the filter do __nothing__ or does the parameter __darken__ the result?

Comment: @TaW, the filter does nothing. `strength` only changes the darkness of the output image which is, actually, never filtered.

Comment: Well, that is not nothing, just not what you want. What are the mask input values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed your function a bit to make it work.
Take care that the strength parameter has no effect in my function. You can play with the bias and factor values to get different results in brightness and so on.

```
    public static Bitmap NonfftSharpen(Bitmap image, double[,] mask, double strength)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)image.Clone();

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            int width = bitmap.Width;
            int height = bitmap.Height;

            if (mask.GetLength(0) != mask.GetLength(1))
            {
                throw new Exception("_numericalKernel dimensions must be same");
            }
            // Create sharpening filter.
            int filterSize = mask.GetLength(0);

            double[,] filter = (double[,])mask.Clone();

            int channels = sizeof(byte);
            double bias = 0.0; // 1.0 - strength;
            double factor = 1.0; // strength / 16.0;

            byte[,] result = new byte[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];

            // Lock image bits for read/write.

            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                                        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            int memorySize = bitmapData.Stride * height;
            byte[] memory = new byte[memorySize];

            // Copy the RGB values into the local array.
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, memory, 0, memorySize);

            int pixel;
            // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    double grayShade = 0.0;

                    for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterSize; filterY++)
                    {


                        for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterSize; filterX++)
                        {

                            int imageX = (x - filterSize / 2 + filterX + width) % width;
                            int imageY = (y - filterSize / 2 + filterY + height) % height;

                            pixel = imageY * bitmapData.Stride + channels * imageX;
                            grayShade += memory[pixel] * filter[filterX, filterY];

                        }

                        int newPixel = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * grayShade + bias), 0), 255);

                        result[x, y] = (byte)newPixel;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    pixel = y * bitmapData.Stride + channels * x;

                    memory[pixel] = result[x, y];
                }
            }

            // Copy the values back to the bitmap.
            Marshal.Copy(memory, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, memorySize);

            // Release image bits.
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            return bitmap;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("input image can't be null");
        }
    }
```

I hope this gets you going :)
Regards